# How to instruct an element to update it's model from outside

Tags: polymer

In my polymer app, I have one element containing a list of items, and another element with the form to CRUD these items.

After inserting a new item from the form-element, how can I instruct the other element to re-pull the model data ? (and thus redraw the list items)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using [Firing custom events](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/polymer.html#fire).

Suppose core-ajax is used for inserting a new item, on core-ajax response fire the event 'insert_done'.

List element should catch that event and get the items, this time with the new one in.

...

This is some general answer, but you can share some code for more specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

Either lookup the list using a dom query and call an update method.  Or, bind a variable that is used to notify the list of the change. Use an observer, in the list element, to execute the update code when the property value is changed by the form element.